# JavaScript Stall Parallel Function Calls

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have create a `TokenService` class with the purpose of returning an access token. The `getToken` function checks if the token has expired and if true, it will try fetching a new accessToken given the refreshToken. However, it is important that only one request goes out attempting to refresh the token. Therefore, if the function gets called in parallel, it needs to wait until the first call has completed and return that result for all other calls.

This is my current implementation:

```
class TokenService {
    private isRefreshing: boolean = false

    public getToken = async (): Promise<string> => {
        const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
        if (!accessToken) return Promise.resolve(null)

        // Check if token has expired
        const { exp } = JSON.parse(atob(accessToken.split('.')[1]))
        if (new Date() < new Date(exp * 1e3))
            return Promise.resolve(accessToken)
            

        if (this.isRefreshing) {
            // Wait for request to finish and return result
        }

        // Refresh token
        this.isRefreshing = true
        const refreshedAccessToken = await this.refreshToken()
        return Promise.resolve(refreshedAccessToken)
    }
}
```

I have added a flag `isRefreshing` indicating if there is currently a refresh request in progress. I am unsure how to go from here. How do I wait for the request to finish and return its result?

Comment: you use `isRefreshing` and `this.isRefreshing` - they are not the same thing

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: `Promise.race([fn1,fn2])` quite the drama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reference `isRefreshing` by going through `this` first - it's not a standalone identifier.

When refreshing the token, assign the result of the Promise to a property on the class. This will let further calls of `getToken` to return that Promise if it exists. If it doesn't exist, and if the current token has expired, generate another.

Because you sometimes do `Promise.resolve(null)`, you sometimes return `null`, not a string, so you should change the type signature of `getToken` appropriately.

```
class TokenService {
    private tokenPromise: null | Promise<string> = null;

    public getToken = async (): Promise<string | null> => {
        const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
        if (!accessToken) return null;
        // Check if token has expired
        const { exp } = JSON.parse(atob(accessToken.split('.')[1]))
        if (new Date() <= new Date(exp * 1e3)) {
            // no need to retrieve another
            return accessToken;
        }
        if (this.tokenPromise) return this.tokenPromise;
        this.tokenPromise = this.refreshToken()
            .catch((error) => {
                window.localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
                return null;
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.tokenPromise = null;
            });
        return this.tokenPromise;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like that `setTimeout` - surely `this.tokenPromise = null` could be done once refreshToken completes :p

Comment: Seems to work but I also have concerns about the setTimeout. As @Bravo said, how could I reset the tokenPromise once it completed?

Comment: perhaps `this.tokenPromise.finally(() => this.tokenPromise = null);`- note, that it's NOT chained to the `.catch` ... though, I think it could be

Comment: You're completely right, don't know what I was thinking

Comment: @CertainPerformance - I too forget that `finally` doesn't change the settled result - that is, when I remember there is a `.finally` :p

Comment: One other thing, since the function is `async` there's no reason to `return Promise.resolve(null)` ... just `return null`